# ASP.Net & 960.gs Integrating the .css files into a new project

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, 960.gs

I've got a full layout designed using 960.gs and am wanting to use it in a ASP.net website but i'm getting warnings such as:

> "Warning File 'css/Reset.css' was not
>   found."
>
> "Warning File 'css/Text.css' was not
>   found."
>
> "Warning File 'css/960.css' was not
>   found."
>
> "Warning File 'css/Base.css' was not
>   found."

I've tried adding a new similarly named folder to the solution explorer and 'add existing item' to add them in but it still seems to cause warnings and intelisense isn't recognising any of the 960.gs classes.

Is there a recommended workflow for importing all of this in?

I should add that it works perfectly well on the local development server and on the webspace, it's seemingly just VS that's complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using '~/css/Reset.css' to denote the site route?